# How can we send message body with multiple attributes in Amazon SQS Event

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have SQS Message which has multiple attributes in body

```
"body": {
    "id": "body127",
    "time": "null",
    "type": "credit-card-accounting.application-accounting",
    "payload": {
        "application_id": "3d6d2a1f78f54735b44f8b86e0db7570ccla",
        "date": "2023-02-14"
    },
    "metadata": {
        "created_at": "2023-02-15T08:02:09.935433Z",
        "service_name": "credit-card-accounting",
        "request_id": "a6bd8261-e452-5652-ba2e-de0777ec6e6b"
    }
}
```

After sending message via Amazon SQS Console, I received formatting error in Lambda.

Is there a specific format for sending message body with multiple attributes in SQS ?

```
"message": "com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'body':
was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true'
or 'false')\
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you are trying to parse your SQS message as JSON. However your SQS message as shown in your question is not valid JSON. You should remove the `"body":` part of the message.

This is valid JSON:

```
{
    "id": "body127",
    "time": "null",
    "type": "credit-card-accounting.application-accounting",
    "payload": {
        "application_id": "3d6d2a1f78f54735b44f8b86e0db7570ccla",
        "date": "2023-02-14"
    },
    "metadata": {
        "created_at": "2023-02-15T08:02:09.935433Z",
        "service_name": "credit-card-accounting",
        "request_id": "a6bd8261-e452-5652-ba2e-de0777ec6e6b"
    }
}
```